# Syncing Google Photos to a Google Cloud bucket

Tags: google-photos, synchronization, google-apps-sync, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to prepare my Google Photos library for distribution to my blog website. Is there a straightforward way to sync Photos to a cloud bucket? The closest thing I'm finding is using client libraries to trigger transfers between them, but it looks like quite a bit of coding is necessary ([see docs here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-transfers#client-libraries)) Is there an easier way to sync Google Photos to Google Cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no easy GUI way to do this. Best way I'd recommend is to script up with rclone which supports Google Photos as well as Google Cloud Storage as backends.

GPhotos: https://rclone.org/googlephotos/#albums
GCS: https://rclone.org/googlecloudstorage/